# Partitioning a Cartesian Product Yields Sierpiński Triangle... ish?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, fractals, set-partition

I wanted to find an efficient method to partition  a Cartesian product of $n$ sets $S_i$ of varying sizes into maximum size subsets that are defined by all tuples in the partition differing in at least $k$ places. I failed to come up with a non-bruteforce algorithm. But I was pretty sure there should be a better approach. So I computed a few partitions by brute force and visualized them to maybe get a new idea. I found that for the case where $k = 2$ using 3 sets of size 100 each, the result seems to be something like what is apparently called *tetrix*, a 3-D Sierpiński Triangle.

I don't understand this result and it did not help me in coming up with an algorithm. But since this is a fractal I am now even more sure there needs to be a non-bruteforce computation to generate this fractal and maybe also a generalization for all possible setups of sets $S_i$ and $k$.

Can anyone explain the result to me and maybe knows how to non-brutoforce generate these partitions?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the code:

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np, pandas as pd, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from tqdm import tqdm

L = [list(range(100)), list(range(100)), list(range(100))]

from itertools import product
def n_distinct_product(iterables, n_distinct):
    elements_n_distinct = set()
    pr = list(product(*iterables))
    for s1 in tqdm(pr):
        if all(sum([w1 != w2 for w1, w2 in zip(s1, s2)]) >= n_distinct
               for s2 in elements_n_distinct if s1 != s2):
            elements_n_distinct.add(tuple(s1))
    return elements_n_distinct


k = 2
data = n_distinct_product(L, k)
data = list(data)

data = np.vstack(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = ['x', 'y', 'z'])


sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

ax = Axes3D(fig)


g = ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, df.z, c=df.z, marker='.', depthshade=True, cmap='Paired')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

# produce a legend with the unique colors from the scatter
legend = ax.legend(*g.legend_elements(), loc="lower center", title="X Values", borderaxespad=-10, ncol=4)
ax.add_artist(legend)

plt.show()

sns.pairplot(data=df)

sns.scatterplot('x', 'y', data=df, hue='z')
```

## Description of algorithm:

Define a set $M = \{\}$. Iterate over Cartesian product in lexicographic order, starting with $(0,0,0)$. For each tuple: If it differs from all tuples in $M$ in at least $k$ places, add it to $M$.

Comment: +1 very interesting observation.

Comment: And $+1$ beautiful images! :-)

Comment: Differing in at least $k$ places is not a [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) on the tuples, and thus not an equivalence relation, so you can't use it to form equivalence classes. Can you describe in more detail what you did?

Comment: @joriki Ok, yes. My formulation was not exact then. I set up the partition so that the property of differing in at least $k$ places holds between all pairs of tuples from the partition. So in that sense I regarded this relation $R$ to also be transitive relative to the so-constructed set. But I guess that is kind of circular logic. Anyway. I did only what is in the code, particularly in `n_distinct_product`; it just gets some set from the whole Cartesian product that satisfies $R$ over all pairs of its elements.

Comment: In that case, understanding your question crucially depends on understanding your code. While I could probably understand it if I spent enough time on it, I'd rather not, and others who don't understand such code won't be able to understand (and thus answer) your question, so I think you should describe the procedure used for constructing the sets in a more mathematical form.

Comment: @joriki Let $C = S_1 \times \dots \times S_n$. Then $\{ x \in C | \forall x' \in C. x \text{ differs in $k$ places from } x' \}$ is a constructed partition.

Comment: That's a property of the sets, that tells us nothing about which sets you actually constructed. For instance, the empty set has that property, but you obviously didn't construct the empty set. The question can't be answered without knowing how you constructed these sets. You still seem to think that they're somehow defined by that property, but they aren't. They're defined by how you constructed them, and so far we can't know how you constructed them without parsing your code.

Comment: @joriki Hm, I don't know... My code does exactly that. I am iterating over the Cartesian product and selecting all elements differing in at least $k$ places from all others that have been collected so far. I can't tell you anything else, because that is exactly what the code does.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood your previous comment. The set you define there is actually the empty set. There is no tuple in $C$ that differs from all other tuple in (at least) $k$ places (if $k\gt1$). You can change every tuple by changing just one component, and you get a tuple that differs from it only in one place. So that can't be what your code does.

Comment: @joriki true. My last comment is the correct description. I have no idea how to state that mathematically without code though.

Comment: You've edited your previous comment. Now it's beginning to form a useful description of the algorithm. Now you just need to state in which order you iterate over the Cartesian product (and add the explanation to the question so that people don't have to read through the comments to understand it).

Comment: @joriki The order is ascending. From $(0,0,0)$ to $(m,m,m)$, where $m = |S_i|$.

Comment: @user3578468: That doesn't define an order. You could go from $(0,0,0)$ to $(m,m,m)$ in many different orders. I suspect you mean the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on the Cartesian product?

Comment: @joriki yes, of course.